# Error CS0103: The name 'ZipFile' does not exist in the current context

Tags: wpf, .net-core

i was working on .net core wpf game lancher but the error "**Error CS0103: The name 'ZipFile' does not exist in the current context**" appeared. even i used the following line: using System.IO.Compression; but it didnt work.

```
        private void DownloadGameCompletedCallback(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string onlineVersion = ((Version)e.UserState).ToString();
                ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(gameZip, rootPath, true); // error cs0103
                File.Delete(gameZip);

                File.WriteAllText(versionFile, onlineVersion);

                VersionText.Text = onlineVersion;
                Status = LauncherStatus.ready;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Status = LauncherStatus.failed;
                MessageBox.Show($"Error finishing download: {ex}");
            }
        }
```

tried change namespace, class to GameLauncher in mainwindow.xaml (didn't work)

Comment: Can you please provide a bit more information? e.g. Where is `gameZip` defined / assigned? Is it a class member? Is it a full qualified path? Does it exists?

Comment: nevermind. so the project is using wpf .net framework so i switch to wpf .net core